# Check if postcode is in multiple arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 different areas, MyArea1, MyArea2, MyArea3. Each of these have an array of postcodes:

```
$myArea1=array("AB1","AC2","AD1");
$myArea2=array("BC1","BC2","BC3");
$myArea3=array("CD1","CD2","CD3");
```

The postcodes I need to check would be like the following "BC2 4YZ".

The following won't work as it checks for a complete match:

```
if (in_array($row['postcode'], $myArea1)) { $Area = 'Area 1'; }
else if (in_array($row['postcode'], $myArea2)) { $Area = 'Area 2'; }    
else if (in_array($row['postcode'], $myArea3)) { $Area = 'Area 3'; }
else { $Area = 'No Match'; }
```

I've got the following that works:

```
foreach ($myArea1 as $myArea1pc) {
    if (strpos($row['postcode'],$myArea1pc) !== false) {
        $Area = 'Area 1';                   
    }
}
```

However is there a way of looping this for all of my arrays?

Edit: There may sometimes be postcodes such as "BC24" in my arrays.

Comment: does `$row['postcode']` contain the string `"BC2 4YZ"` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes, that will obviously vary in each row, but in that example it's BC2 4YZ, potentially BC24YZ, BC2 4YX, bc24yz etc, but it will contain BC2.

Comment: should it find matches at all arrays OR stop at the first occurrence?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest there will only be one postcode in the row and once it finds the match, it doesn't need to continue, likewise, if there's no match in any of my arrays, I simply want $Area to have the value "No Match".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to use `in_array` for this.

```
$input = $row['postcode'];

$areas = array(
    'Area 1' => array("AB1","AC2","AD1"),
    'Area 2' => array("BC1","BC2","BC3"),
    'Area 3' => array("CD1","CD2","CD3"),
);

// Take out the first 3 letter:
$part = substr(trim(str_replace(' ', '', $input)), 0, -3);

$Area = 'No match';
// Find which "area" array contains it
foreach ($areas as $k => $v) {
    if (in_array($part, $v)) {
        $Area = $k;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only issue is, and this is my fault for not mentioning it in the original post, there may sometimes be 4 characters in the first part of the postcode, for example "BC24 4YX", taking the first 3 characters will see that as "BC2"

Comment: Is it always separated by a space?

Comment: Not always bud, sometimes it won't be separated at all. I've been having a play with what you've done and was wondering whether something like this may work: `foreach ($postcodes as $a => $b) { foreach ($b as $c) { if (strpos($row['postcode'],$c) !== false) { $Area = $a; } else { $Area = 'No Match'; } } }` However I've found that as there are no commas separating the postcodes, strpos won't work...

Comment: And the rest (not the area part) is always 3 chars or that also may varry?

Comment: I edited my answer, check it out if it fits your needs.